# Is it possible to remotely retrieve available SSID's and their respective RSSI values from an apple device(iPhone,iPad, iPod) without a native app?

Tags: iphone, wifi, rssi, ssid

we are trying to physically track devices(owned by the organization) indoors within our organization.

Is there a way to remotely access the list of SSID's in range of a particular device without a native app installed on the device?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible with the publicly available iOS SDK.

Most indoor positioning systems work from the network side to trace devices, not the other way around, e.g.: http://www.ruckuswireless.com/products/smart-wireless-services/location-services